# Angular + Docker + Nginx + Kubernetes - Deployment issue. Application doesn't start up due to missing js files

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, kubernetes, deployment

When deploying my Angular application to production I'm having an issue where my application can't see/use the bundled scripts generated on build (runtime, main, css, etc.)

***Background:***

I have a domain which is already hosting a web application (probably an HTML application defined by webapp.xml, we can consider this as sort of Legacy application) . Now I'm trying to deploy my new angular application to same domain on sub-directory level using docker image on Kubernetes. Everything goes good till the deployment, but when I try to launch the new application from browser by calling `http://appname-platform-env.dev.xxxx.aws/app2` my new application can only find the `index.html` file but can't see/use the bundled scripts generated on build (runtime.js, main.js, css, poyfills.js,etc.)

Existing app hosted in :- http://appname-platform-env.dev.xxxx.aws.com/app1

My app (which I just deployed) :- http://appname-platform-env.dev.xxxx.aws.com/app2 (this is the state I'm expecting)

Below are my files (nginx.conf,dockerfile,k8's ingress file, angular.json)

1.Dockerfile

```
# stage1 as builder
FROM node:latest as builder

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && mkdir /my-app && mv ./node_modules ./my-app

WORKDIR /my-app

COPY . .

# Build the project and copy the files
RUN npm run ng build  --prod  --output-path="dist/app2" --deploy-url="/app2"

FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stahg 1
COPY --from=builder /my-app/dist/app2  /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {   
        listen 8080;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
}
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: appname-ingress
 namespace: app-env
 annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "http://appname-platform-env.dev.xxxx.aws:8080/" 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "$scheme://$http_host/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: appname-platform-env.dev.xxxx.aws
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app2  ##Front end
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /app2/
```

folder structure
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62NuT.png)

Comment: Where are you doing the routing to app2? there is only one path in your ingress spec.

Comment: @jordanm Sorry, I had a typo earlier to the ingress file while just posting here. Now, I have updated it. This is how my ingress file looks like

Comment: You can try to change your base href to `<base href="/app2">` inside `index.html` of the angular app. This should do it.